# Handlebars expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, handlebars.js, keystonejs

I have encounter a handlebars expression `{{!< default}}` which I do not understand. Before asking this question I have tried to search for answers on Google. However, I could not find any answers to it. Could anyone explain what this expression mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In handlebars, the expression `{{!   }}` is used for comments like this:

```
{{! This is a comment in handlebars }}
```

Therefore, your `{{!< default}}` expression is a comment and produces no output.